# DevOps integration of Addon deploys

Tags: add-on, ecl-connector

We have an ECL connector developed using Tridion Integration framework. As of Today, it is deployed manually from the addon portal. Can this deploy be done via DevOps tools? Are there any AddOn APIs exposed for such purposes?

Thanks
Rites

Answer (score 3):

You can check Tridion Add-on Service API definition using following url

[YourAddOnServiceUrl]/addon/api/api-docs/index.html

If you enabled Access Management security on you Add-on Service you will need to acquire access token from it before calling Add-on Service API. In order to upload add-on package you will need access token from user that has Add-on Service Administrator role.